# Too many authentication failures for ubuntu mina deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

When we do `ssh` it works fine but when we do `mina deploy` it gives `Too many authentication failures for ubuntu` this error.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue add `set :ssh_options, "-o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'"` to your `config/deploy.rb`